# a button disappear on saving all rows in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i have that grid [grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGc1H.png)

[image]

but whenever i click on save ll rows it gives me that 
[after saving rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54D51.png)

[image]

and here is my code

```js
colModel: [
    { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 180, editable : true,
      edittype:"custom", id : "CustomerID",
      editoptions: { custom_element: function(value, options) {
          var parts = value.split(' ');
          var elemStr = '<div><input size="6" value="' + parts[0] +
                        '" /><input type="button" size="5" value="..." /></div>';
          // return DOM element from jQuery object
          return $(elemStr)[0];
      },
      custom_value: function(elem) {
          var inputs = $("input", $(elem)[0]);
          var first = inputs[0].value;
          return first ;
      }}

    },
],
```

```js
function saveAllRows(){
     var ids = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', ids[i]);
    }
}
```

so when clicking on save all rows the button disappear .. but i want it to appear .. any help .. thanks a lot

Comment: If you want get answers on your questions then you should answer on comments which one write to your questions. By the way, if you want to hold all rows in editing mode then you need just call `editRow` directly answer calling of `saveRow` (for every row).

Comment: then how to save all row except button ??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What you mean with "except button"? What you want to implement?

Comment: Why you start editing in *multiple rows* (all rows)? It mean that changes made by the user in one row *should stay unchanged* if the user click on another row. The standard behavior is editing *one row* at one and the user saves the editing row by pressing of Enter key or by clicking on the "Save" button. The editing can be started either by clicking on "Edit" button or just on Click/Double-Click on the row. One can have either editing buttons in every row or editing buttons in "navigator bar" (near the pager)

Comment: for example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) (or [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap.htm)) contains buttons in every row, form editing and inline editing buttons in the navigator bar and it starts form editing on double-click on the row. One implements typically ether inline editing or form editing, but the demo shows just the mix of both plus filtering and paging.

Comment: @mermer Also the images in the links of your question are empty. Please make sure the question is clear enough and any external links are valid.